# Is it possible to use a flatbuffer as the state store for redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, flatbuffers

I'd like to use redux but instead of a javascript object for the state I'd like to use a flatbuffer. How could I do this?

Comment: Not familiar with Redux, but FlatBuffers produces plain byte arrays. If Redux can store those, it should work.

Comment: This is effectively the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941079/why-redux-store-should-be-serializable .  See the answer there.