# Storing models in Redux, good? Bad?

Tags: javascript, model, redux

I've been wondering for a while now... I have an application, which get data from an API, classic. Say we get `User` objects sent by the API. I then store these objects as is in Redux, so they are simple objects.

Now when I need to use them, I retrieve them and ALWAYS need to pass them to my `User` model in order to get access to useful functions like say `getFullName` or `getCompleteAddress`.

My question is, wouldn't it be easier/simpler, to store the models in Redux and so have them ready from the beginning? Or is that a bad design?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against this.
Redux is meant to store serializable state. Functions are not serializable and worse of all, when storing functions you're possible also storing their scope and opening Pandora's box with that.

If you're trying to create classical OOP models (Which I'm guessing from your question) with their state and methods inside the same object you will be better off using the redux stored object for constructing that model.

An alternative approach is to not mix state and method inside the model. At least that's how I would approach this. Create a module with a function to create the model that acts as a constructor for your objects. Then separate the methods into additional functions that act on a given instance of your model.

So instead of doing this:

```js
class User {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  isLegal() {
    return this.age >= 18
  }
}
```

I would do this for modelling:

```js
export function CreateUser(name, age) {
  return {
  name: name,
  age: age
  }
}

export function IsLegal(user) {
  return user.age >= 18
}
```

But that's just my opinion, man!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I'll follow that path

Comment: Also see the [Redux FAQ entry on why you should only have serializable values in the store](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-non-serializable).

Answer (score 1):

You should only have plain objects in your store. This is because model instance methods are unserializable.

See this thread: [Why redux store should be serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941079/why-redux-store-should-be-serializable)

You can always write selectors for the computed properties.

Learn about using selectors here: https://github.com/reactjs/reselect

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish I could select 2 answers. Voted you up instead.