# Why is a Map in JS considered non serializable in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When using redux and you try to store a map into it, you get an error:

> A non-serializable value was detected in the state

Why is that? I know the doc says you can't but it doesn't explain why. Because you can't directly JSON.stringify a map? But you can do something like this...

```
m = new Map()
m.set("1", "2")
JSON.stringify([...m]);
```

Comment: "*Because you can't directly JSON.stringify a map?*" correct. "*But you can do something like this...*" you're just demonstrating how you're **not** serialising a map but an array of key-value pairs.

Comment: "Why did project X make decision Y" questions are usually not suited to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder we actually have a Q&A [Why redux store should be serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40941079) - the answer is just a quote from the documentation. This question is asking why is the map not serialisable and...I honestly cannot answer it more meaningfully than "because it's not". Which is already included in the question, as well.

Comment: Any object that has methods attached to it is not serializable.  Of course any object can implement it's own system for converting to and from JSON, but Redux wouldn't be aware of that conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map *can under specific cirumstances* be serializable and de-serializable *if you provide the logic by that by hand*, using `map.entries()` and `Map.fromEntries(...)`.

Assuming that all keys and values of the map are themselves serializable - which is not necessarily the case, since maps can take any object as a key (and value, of course).

It cannot be serialized automatically by calling `JSON.serialize` in a way that would allow you to reconstruct it by calling `JSON.parse` - and that is what most tools rely on.

So, using a Map could break middleware like `redux-persist` (unless you add more logic there) and countless others and sometimes even (depending on what you put in here and what you use as keys) even go so far as to crash your DevTools.

Since a map that only contains serializable values & keys has no real benefits over just using a normal object for the same purpose, we recommend just using plain JavaScript objects instead of maps.

Comment: What about sequence guarantees? Maps can guarantee the sequence of keys unlike objects since not all browsers can guarantee ES2015 or later behaviour.

Comment: @Va5ili5 Can you name a browser that is still being supported by the vendor that cannot guarantee that behavior in 2022?

Comment: I am not sure. Just researching I saw that a main benefit of a Map vs an Object is this guarantee. It is very likely that this used to be an issue an no longer is.

Comment: @Va5ili5 Well, ES2015 was 2015. That is 7 years in the past. There is no browser on the market anymore that does not value insertion order. Also, that guarantee is something that would only be a benefit in very rare edge cases.